# ELF file variable addresses of C structure in debug info

Tags: gcc, linker, elf, dwarf

I have .elf file. I am trying to learn symbol address. I could find main variable addresses with many ways. I used pyelftools, nm.exe, objdump.exe, readelf.exe. But all of these ways i can't reach structure addresses and enum values. When I debug elf file with dwarf i can see structure and enum. I can follow dwarf properties but is complicated. How can i find structure variable addresses and enum values easily and automatically?

Edit:
I will explain my question with an example.

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 1350 entries:    
  Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name   
 1192: 200005c8    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 arm_adc_B
```

When we look symbol table, there are 1350 entries. For example i want to learn "arm_adc_B" symbol properties and it has structure parameter or not. For learnig these things we must look .debug_info section.

```
 <1><414e>: Abbrev Number: 37 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <414f>   DW_AT_specification: <0x3f45>
    <4153>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <4154>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 53
    <4155>   DW_AT_location    : 5 byte block: 3 c8 5 0 20  (DW_OP_addr: 200005c8)
```

Firstly I searched address "200005c8" in dwarf text and find DW_OP_addr: 200005c8. After that followed DW_AT_specification:<0x3f45>.

```
 <1><3f45>: Abbrev Number: 35 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <3f46>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2b49): arm_adc_B
    <3f4a>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3f4b>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 63
    <3f4c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3efc>
    <3f50>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <3f50>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
```

When I follow this address, i can receive its type.

```
<1><3eb3>: Abbrev Number: 10 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <3eb4>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 12
    <3eb5>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3eb6>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 43
    <3eb7>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x3eec>
 <2><3ebb>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_member)
    <3ebc>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x26d8): ADC_Start
    <3ec0>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3ec1>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 44
    <3ec2>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3782>
    <3ec6>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0
 <2><3ec7>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_member)
    <3ec8>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x26e2): ADC_Start1
    <3ecc>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3ecd>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 45
    <3ece>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3782>
    <3ed2>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 4
 <2><3ed3>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_member)
    <3ed4>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x285a): MSDI_ChartMode
    <3ed8>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3ed9>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 46
    <3eda>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3e84>
    <3ede>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 8
 <2><3edf>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_member)
    <3ee0>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x2b2b): msdi_tx_data
    <3ee4>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 15
    <3ee5>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 47
    <3ee6>   DW_AT_type        : <0x3eec>
    <3eea>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 9
 <2><3eeb>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

"arm_adc_B" variable is a structure parameter. We can calculate structure members address. It is starting from 200005c8 you need to add DW_AT_data_member_location only.

```
arm_adc_B                                           0x200005c8    
arm_adc_B.ADC_Start                                 0x200005c8    
arm_adc_B.ADC_Start1                                0x200005cc    
arm_adc_B.MSDI_ChartMode                            0x200005d0    
arm_adc_B.msdi_tx_data                              0x200005d1
```

I want to find this addresses. There are DW_TAG_enumeration_type. We can learn like this way. How i can do that easily?

Comment: Your question makes no sense: what is a "structure variable address"? Do you mean "field offsets _within_ the structure" or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks for your answer. I gave an example.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Cut/paste the text instead.

Comment: Okay. I did it. @EmployedRussian

Comment: Try [DWARF Explorer](https://github.com/sevaa/dwex) to eyeball the whole DWARF tree and see how do DIEs interact. Disclaimer: I wrote that.

Comment: Yes. I knew. I used it , it is very useful. Thank you. @SevaAlekseyev

Answer (score 1):

> How i can do that easily?

The info you seek is *only* available as part of debug info (DWARF). There is *no shortcut* -- you must decode DWARF one way or another.

You can however leverage libraries intended to simplify working with DWARF. [libdwarf](https://www.prevanders.net/dwarf.html) is one such library. [gimli](https://github.com/gimli-rs/gimli) is another.